# Format entries in list to 8 bit binary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, format

I have a list `A = [100011, 1110110]`. I want to make each entry in the list 8 bit using the format option:

```
B = '{0:08b}'.format(A[1])
B = '{0:08b}'.format(A[2])
```

But when I `print(B)`. I am getting the output as: `B = 100001111000001011110` and `B = 11000011010101011`

Why is this happening? Is this command not used for list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integer literals defined in the list `A` are specified in decimals. You should specify them as binary literals (prefixed with `0b`) instead:

```
A = [0b100011, 0b1110110]
print('{0:08b}'.format(A[0]))
print('{0:08b}'.format(A[1]))
```

This outputs:

```
00100011
01110110
```

Comment: As with all formatting options, if the result doesn't fit in the specified length the length is expanded. Good catch on the constants.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thank you. That helped.